# What are the best practices to have debates in GenAI Meta?

Tags: discussion, debates, meta

Let me start to explain what I mean by debate.

In certain social groups, a debate is a formal event, i.e., some countries have debates about candidates for public positions, like in the United States of America presidential elections. These events have a moderator and debating rules intended to show the audience the political stance of the candidates on some topics. Commonly, one topic should be the new president's priorities, and the rules might include participation time limits, among other things.

A debate can also refer to informal discussions where participants present arguments, which can be emotional, logical, or based on facts and objections. Arguments are reasons presented to support a particular point of view or to challenge it.

On Stack Exchange, there is a long tradition of having informal debates. There is a place to have some of these debates, per-meta-sites and Meta Stack Exchange, which have debate categories: [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), and [bug](/questions/tagged/bug). Sometimes even on posts tagged, [support](/questions/tagged/support) occurs debates.

It's known that post-votes are used to show agreement and disagreement. The system is set to advise adding a comment when a "new" user downvote a post.

Some users might ask post authors to be clear about their claims. Sometimes this might be done by requiring statistics, information about how to reproduce a system behavior, reference to trusted sources, etc.

Several debates are open in GenAI Meta, like the site name, scope, and privilege thresholds.

So, as the title says, what practices would we like to adopt in GenAI Meta for our debates?

---

To simplify the process of finding answers to this question, I suggest using a current local debate as a reference. As stated on [What happened with the stakeholder community group the week of July 28th](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/115/12), the site's scope is currently under discussion. Do you believe this debate showcases effective methods for managing debates within GenAI?

Comment: Are you suggesting that this site should do things differently to every other SE site?

Comment: @Chenmunka It seems that you have an objection. Could you please provide more details while staying on topic with the question at hand?

Comment: No objection.  Just that all SE sites have debates on their meta sites, that is what meta is for.  I feel your question is either superfluous, or is proposing that we do something radically different here.

Comment: @Chenmunka Remember that we do not require users that join this site to be familiar with the Stack Exchange (SE). While users might not be familiar with SE they still might have experience participating in debates on online communities. I have already mentioned meta sites and what they are for. This question is asking for best practices. I did my best to not induce any practice, common or radically different.

Comment: I just found a related question in Meta Stack Exchange: [A Proposal for More Constructive Downvoting on Meta: Express Disagreement by Answering the Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193884/1359324).  This question was created in 2013. It has a score of +130 and 10 answers. The top answer has +65 score, and the 2nd answers have a score of +25. There are other answers also with positive scores. There are multiple comments. I plan to read this this weekend.

Answer (score 2):

> what practices would we like to adopt in GenAI Meta for our debates?

If it fits the QA format, use https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com. Otherwise use some chatroom.

Comment: Please provide more details, and if it's possible provide examples or links. Also please be more specific about using the chatroom. Do you suggest using the first GenAI chatroom for everything? Should there be a specific chatroom for debates?

Comment: @Wicket using the first GenAI chatroom for everything. Fork if that becomes a mess.

Answer (score 2):

According to [What is "meta"? How does it work?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta), this is the place that is intended to have debates.

> Unlike normal Stack Exchange sites, Meta invites the community to discuss, debate and propose changes to the way the community itself behaves, as well as how the software itself works.

Moreover, every site in Stack Exchange has been debating in Meta even the most successful site like Stack Overflow. So, I would suggest that just debate here in Meta and use what the system provides to do. It has always been the best practice even though it is not the most efficient way to do.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, the debate must have a format that is healthy and facilitates follow-up. The truth is I'm not an active reddit user but I like that its format looks a lot like ArgDown if I'm not mistaken I think they implement it (I refrain from commenting on that community).

1. ArgDown is a simple and structured notation used to represent
   arguments and debates in a human-readable format. Its main goal is
   to help visualize and analyze arguments in a clear and concise
   manner. The ArgDown format mainly consists of three types of
   elements: statements, arguments, and relationships.
2. Statements: These are affirmations or propositions that can be made
   by different parties in a debate. They can be affirmative or
   negative.
3. Arguments: They represent the support or refutation of a statement.
   An argument has one or more premises and a conclusion. They are used
   to present logical reasoning.

Relationships: These describe how statements and arguments are connected. They can be of different types, such as "supports," "refutes," "replaces," etc.

We have two statements, A and B, representing two opposing perspectives on the cause of climate change. Then, we present two arguments, each with its premises and conclusions, which support or refute statements A and B, respectively. The relationship "A supports 1" indicates that argument 1 supports statement A, while "B refutes 1" points out that argument 2 refutes the conclusion of argument 1.

Example of ArgDown:

```
[Statement]
A: Climate change is caused by human activities.

[Statement]
B: There is not enough scientific evidence to support the idea that climate change is caused by human activities.

[Argument]
1. [Premise]
   A: The increase in greenhouse gas concentration in the atmosphere has been primarily caused by human activities, such as burning fossil fuels and deforestation.

   [Conclusion]
   A: Therefore, climate change is caused by human activities.

[Argument]
2. [Premise]
   B: Climate changes have occurred throughout Earth's history due to natural factors, and the current climate change cannot be entirely attributed to human activities.

   [Conclusion]
   B: The idea that climate change is caused by human activities lacks sufficient scientific evidence.

[Relationship]
A supports 1
B refutes 1
```

The ArgDown format facilitates the visualization and analysis of debates and the relationships between statements and arguments involved in a specific topic.