# How can I verify if GenAI Stack Exchange has reached a consensus on a Meta topic?

Tags: discussion, meta

The site scope is one of the core attributes discussed since the Stakeholders group was created on July 5th, 2023. One month later, it is still being discussed.

The first post on GenAI Meta, this site, [What is on-topic on GenAI SE?](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/12), shares the progress of the Stakeholders group. After it, several new posts about the [site-scope](/questions/tagged/site-scope) have been created.

We can't rely on the accepted answer feature as it depends on the OP's decision on what answer they want to accept. This decision might be or not aligned with the community consensus; that is entirely up to the OP's will.

Votes might not be reliable either, as upvotes and downvotes are privileges:

- People being new users cannot participate in voting immediately after joining GenAI Stack Exchange as upvote privilege requires a +15 rep. and the downvote privilege requires +125 rep.
- People with the association bonus can upvote, but they can't downvote immediately after joining GenAI Stack Exchange as the downvote privilege requires +125 rep.

On the other hand, posts on Meta usually are "open" for edits, getting new answers and getting new votes, as "close question" feature is intended to avoid having new answers only. The only way to prevent a post from getting new edits and new votes is by using the "lock" feature.

**Question** : How can I verify if GenAI Stack Exchange has reached a consensus on a Meta topic?

##### Related

###### Local

- [What are the best practices to have debates in GenAI Meta?](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/79/12)

###### Meta Stack Exchange

- [Should Discussion Questions have an Accepted Answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61760/1359324)
- [If votes works differently on meta sites how does that of accepting answers work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96039/1359324)

Answer (score -1):

The public Q&A platform hasn't particular indicators to signal that the community has reached a consensus when discussing a topic in Meta. Someone may feature the community consensus somehow, and the community might act to show their agreement or disagreement. Usually, "someone" is a **diamond moderator**. A diamond moderator might be Community Manager (staff), pro-tempore or elected community moderator (non-staff).

As mentioned in the question:

- The **accepted answer** only reflects the OP's opinion / preference.
- Post score (votes) is not always a good indicator because

  - Votes require privileges
  - People might vote as they will despite the guidance provided
  - They can only be changed if the post is edited.

Elements that might be used to feature the community consensus

- **Comments**: They have length and formatting limitations but might be hidden under certain circumstances and deleted if they get enough flags.
- **Questions and answers** (posts)
  They are better than comments because:

  - More visibility.
  - More formatting options than comments.
  - Revision history.
  - Post timeline.
  - They might be marked as Community Wiki to allow anyone to edit them.

    - Questions might be converted automatically into a Community Wiki after getting a certain number of edits from different users or by a diamond moderator
    - Answers might be marked as Community Wiki by the answer creator.
  - Diamond moderators might apply

    - Moderator-only tags like [faq](/questions/tagged/faq), [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) and [featured](/questions/tagged/featured).
    - Post notices to questions and answers.
- Tour, help homepage, and help articles.

  - Only diamond moderators can edit them.

Diamond moderators might find this responsibility challenging, especially when the are involved in the discussion.

#### References

- [How is consensus determined on Meta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177550/289691)